# How to look for evidence of a stock that got suddenly halted during regular trading hour in the NASDAQ exchange?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, stock-exchanges, cfd

Yesterday (May 14th, 2020) I was trading CFD on Co-Diagnostics (CODX). Then at 13:25 EDT the stock halted in the NASDAQ exchange and it was until 13:58 EDT that the market resumed (subsequently my trade got suspended on my trading platform and I experienced some glitches that led to further losses).

May I ask if there is any way I could get evidence that the stock halted between 13:25 EDT to 13:58 EDT?

Comment: NASDAQ makes them known: https://www.nasdaqtrader.com/trader.aspx?id=TradeHalts#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](https://www.nasdaqtrader.com/trader.aspx?id=TradingHaltHistory) and click "May 14, 2020". It lists two halts for CODX, one 13:25-13:30 and the other 13:48-13:58.

Answer (score 1):

Trading halts can be found here:

[NASDAQ](https://www.nasdaqtrader.com/trader.aspx?id=TradeHalts)

[CBOE](https://markets.cboe.com/us/equities/market_statistics/halts/)